# Need to display new form while serialport write

Tags: c#, serial-port

Trying to display a new form that says "Please Swipe Card" while the IDTECH card writer is waiting for a swipe.

```
private void writecard(string track1) //string track2)
    {

        SerialPort sp1 = new SerialPort(encoderport, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        sp1.ReadTimeout = 10000;

        if (sp1.IsOpen == true)
        {
            sp1.Close();
        }


        sp1.Open();
        sp1.Write(new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x77 }, 0, 2);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        sp1.Write(new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x73 }, 0, 2);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        sp1.Write(new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x01 }, 0, 2);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        sp1.Write(track1);                              // Track 1
        Thread.Sleep(100);


        sp1.Write(new byte[] { 0x3f, 0x1c }, 0, 2);
        swipeform swipepop = new swipeform();
        swipepop.ShowDialog();                        // **Problem**



        Thread.Sleep(100);

        try
        {
            swipepop.Close();                         // **Problem**
            int firstChar = sp1.ReadChar();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            string data = String.Concat(Convert.ToChar(firstChar), sp1.ReadExisting());
            //textBox3.Text = String.Format(data);
            if (data != "")
            {
                char result = data[1];
                if (result == '0')
                    MessageBox.Show("Encoding Successful");

                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Encoding Failed - Please try again");
            }
        }
        catch (System.TimeoutException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Timed out.  Please try again.");
            sp1.Write(new byte[2] { 0x1b, 0x61 }, 0, 2);
        }
        sp1.Close();
    }
```

The issue that I am having is that once the writecard method is called the swipeform pops up and the device wants you to swipe. But once you swipe the form stays and will not close and the method does not continue until you close the swipeform.

Comment: I tried to use a do while loop which sorta works however the dialog box never closes unless I hit the X. I thought it would stay open While X = 1

Answer (score 1):

`Form.ShowDialog()` is blocking. That means it won't return before the form is closed.

One of the solutions will be: Check the serial port within your `swipepop` form. You can pass your `SerialPort` object via the constructor of your form.